# EXC_BREAKPOINT - UIAccessibilityTraitButton

Tags: swift

I am getting EXC_BREAKPOINT errors via CrashAnalytics and I couldn't find out why. Error is generated from the line labeled as "HERE". I am also getting the same error from the same line from a different tableview.

Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionViewCell
        cell.data = self.JSONDATA?[indexPath.row]

        let fav = self.JSONDATA?[indexPath.row]["is_favorite"].bool

        if fav == false {
            let image = UIImage(named: "cha-plus.png")
            cell.favButton.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.favButton.accessibilityLabel = "Text Here"
HERE -----> cell.favButton.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
        }else{
            let image = UIImage(named: "cha-minus-blue.png")
            cell.favButton.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.favButton.accessibilityLabel = "Text Here"
            cell.favButton.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
        }
```

Comment: are you sure `favButton` is not `nil`?

Comment: If it is nil, I should get the same error from the lines above it, I am correct?

Comment: yeap, my bad, didn't notice. Just can't imagine how else can it crash on assigning some value.

Comment: Can you share the full stack, redacting your app's name if necessary?

Comment: As this is run time crash so it may be possible that you favButton accessibility removed in nib files. You can check in nib files.